# Parsing members of a variable length python string

Tags: python, string, sed

I am using sed in python to read the text from a log file into a single string.

Here is the command:

```
sys_output=commands.getoutput('sed -n "/SYS /,/Tot /p" %s.log' % cim_input_prefix)
```

and here is a printout of sys_output

```
SYS   SCFTYP  METHOD     NC   NO   NU  NBS  MEMORY    CPU TIME    
   1   RHF     CCSD       18   21   59   89      92      1.6163 
   2   RHF     CCSD        4    7   22   36       2      0.0036  
 Tot                                             94      1.6199 
 SYS   SCFTYP  METHOD     NC   NO   NU  NBS  MEMORY    CPU TIME
   1   RHF     CCSD        4    4   14   19       1      0.0002
 Tot                                              1      0.0002
 SYS   SCFTYP  METHOD     NC   NO   NU  NBS  MEMORY    CPU TIME
   1   RHF     CCSD        4    9   36   55       8      0.0416
   2   RHF     CCSD       18   25   73  108     200      5.3587
   3   RHF     CCSD        4   10   29   48       6      0.0217
 Tot                                            214      5.4221
```

Which has three groups, with [2,1,3] rows of interest.

The log files my script will encounter may have a variable number of groups and rows, so I can't simply split the string and pull out the useful information.

I am interested in the index of group and row, and the memory column.

How can I parse this large string to obtain a dictionary such as:

```
{'1-1': 92, '1-2': 2, '2-1': 1, '3-1': 8, '3-2': 200, '3-3': 6}?
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I've tried saving sys_output to a text file, and saving a count of the number of subsystems by finding the number of lines which start with an integer. I can perhaps express the index of the memory value in terms of the number of subsystems, if I can get a count of how many grups there are in a similar way.

Comment: Why can't you use split to obtain the information? i think it's gonna work.

Comment: Say I have a file with only 1 subsystem in the 1st group, and 3 subsystems in the 2nd group. Then, my indexes will change because of the SYS- and Tot- lines. I'm concurrently trying to remove those lines by modifying my sed command, which should make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kind of state machine based on the particular traits of the output may make life easier than worrying too much about indices.

This snippet works with the example and could be tailored to handle corner cases.

```
import collections

with open("cpu_text", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

group_id = 0
group_member_id = 0
output_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

for line in lines:
    if line.find("SYS") > -1:
        group_id += 1
    elif line.find("Tot") > -1:
        group_member_id = 0
    else:
        group_member_id += 1
        key = "{0}-{1}".format(group_id, group_member_id)
        memory = line.split()[7]
        output_dict[key] = memory

print(output_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
OrderedDict([('1-1', '92'), ('1-2', '2'), ('2-1', '1'), ('3-1', '8'), ('3-2', '200'), ('3-3', '6')])
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, and is a useful way to approach the problem. Thanks a lot.